# jquery: ajax track progress of request inc images and other assets in load time

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, progress, addeventlistener

Basically, i want track progress of my application with percentage, when sending `AJAX` request but important part to include images loading, so ajax request should only complete once all the images / css 100% fully loaded.

I know you can track progress either using the HTML5 `addEventListener("progress", function(e) {}`  or repeatedly calling a `setTimeout` function.

But neither approach say when images  on the page are fully loaded. Other option is to use `.load()` for images, but this does not track progress?

So my question, is it possible to load images and track progress within ajax?, or load 50 odd images using individual `ajax` requests.

any idea or sample code will be very hopeful.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up using  this library `PreloadJS`.  Which is pretty easy to use and does most of what i needed :

http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS